# NameServer ns3-02.azure-dns.org. should be in proper format

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

After creating **DNS zone** in azure I opened my domain name cpanel and add nameservers then it gives following error:
[image: Azure error]
**NameServer ns3-02.azure-dns.org. should be in proper format**

I was looking for this error in google but I haven't found any solutions. I want to host my blogging site on azure.

Comment: Could you try removing the trailing dots at the end?

Comment: yes by removing dot my nameservers are updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps are correct. If you encounter this problem, it should be a problem with the domain name provider.

Juunas's suggestion is right, adding nameservers does not require dots at the end.

According to your description, I tried it myself, and finally failed to solve the problem in my panel. The operation steps are correct. Finally, contact godaddy, let the customer service staff operate in the background, and finally solve the problem. The steps are exactly the same.

I saw your screenshot, it should not be godaddy, **please contact the service provider for assistance**.

[image]