# How to transfer out a domain from Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, appdomain

Hi i am trying to transfer out a domain from Microsoft Azure to GoDaddy.

After unlocking the domain, fetching the authorization code.
I entered the domain & authorization code in GoDaddy and paid the transfer fee.

After some time the GoDaddy status showed: **The sending registrar rejected the transfer**.
I checked everything on azure, but everything is fine (Domain is unlocked, Authorization Code was correct etc.) but still no clue why it is happening.

I tried Azure support, but it is $29/month and for free support they told to ask question here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/community)

Anyone else faced the issue?

Please help.

Comment: Same problem like me, but no solution. (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure/transfer-domain-from-azure-to-another-registrar/m-p/1361854)

Comment: You can refer my answer in my posts([post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63534525/nameserver-ns3-02-azure-dns-org-should-be-in-proper-format/63554124#63554124),[post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63478958/purchase-a-domain-name-for-static-web-applications/63497561#63497561)). These two posts tell you how to replace the nameserver. If it still fails after trying, it is recommended to raise a support ticket to consult the official.

Comment: Hi Jason. Thanks. But i wanted to transfer the domain to someone else, changing nameserver was working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Azure support and they provided the below steps. (It worked!)

1. In Azure, open the domain resource. Under domain management, Open Advanced Management Portal.
2. On the Management portal, click on the domain you are going to transfer.
3. **Scroll down to Privacy Settings, Click 'Remove domains by proxy' and be sure to turn Privacy off.**
4. Scroll down to Additional Settings, turn off Domain Lock.
5. On Additional Settings, click on Transfer my domain away from Azure.
6. Follow the onscreen suggestions presented. Click on Continue with transfer.
7. An "EPP Code" will be generated. The customer will need to present this code to his new registrar.
8. After 12-24 hours of the Transfer being initiated, open again the Advanced Management Portal. Click on the Domains drop down list. Select the Transfers option.
9. The domain you wish to transfer should appear on this list. Select it and click on Accept Transfer.
10. After all the data has been validated, the new registrar will approve the request.

Comment: These was also documented at the bottom of this post: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/08/FAQ-App-Service-Domain-and-Custom-Domains.html

This is outdated as of Feb 2023. There is no "Advanced Management" section now. Instead, the troubleshooting section has this text:

"Transferring a domain out ... to another registrar is supported via API and PowerShell. You'll need to get an authorization code which you can take to your registrar of choice to proceed with transferring out of your domain."
https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/09/22/2021-Managing-ASD#transfering-domain-out