# How can i host an ASP.Net web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localhost, publish, host

i tried to **publish my ASP.NET web application** to many ways such as *FTP, Folder,and Azure*
put it didn't work with me with ***url ([www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com))***
so i tried to host it online with *GoDaddy and Hostinger* also didn't work.
What is the best way to host my website with this URL?

Comment: there are too many tutorials online -  `didn't work` What did not work ? the name? the site ? what is the error, what are your steps to publish it ?

Comment: @Njoud You may need to advise full error message here. Since you are using Godaddy, they are using Plesk control panel, you use WebDeploy to publish your .net application, please just read https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-using-web-deploy-with-plesk-control-panel/

Answer (score 0):

For the best hosting experience with ASP.NET projects, I recommend [Azure Cloud Hosting](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/apps/search/?&ef_id=Cj0KCQjwqKuKBhCxARIsACf4XuGptNs2e0KnsjdYGOhitC3ZznfOGY2tz8GlpUeKFkwutbGyln75SssaAiWQEALw_wcB:G:s&OCID=AID2200247_SEM_Cj0KCQjwqKuKBhCxARIsACf4XuGptNs2e0KnsjdYGOhitC3ZznfOGY2tz8GlpUeKFkwutbGyln75SssaAiWQEALw_wcB:G:s&gclid=Cj0KCQjwqKuKBhCxARIsACf4XuGptNs2e0KnsjdYGOhitC3ZznfOGY2tz8GlpUeKFkwutbGyln75SssaAiWQEALw_wcB). In there you can [define a new Web App Service and deploy your website directly from Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=netcore31&pivots=development-environment-vs).
If you already have a domain you can [transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65177260/3085925) it to Azure.

Comment: first, Thank you dobre.b

Comment: second, i tried Azure put the URL contains (mywebsite.Azure.com)

Comment: You have to buy a domain and then associate it with your Web App Service called mywebsite.Azure.com . If you already have one, then you can transfer it to Azure (I posted the documentation for this).